# How to print to the console in CPUlator ARMv7

Tags: assembly, console, arm, printf

I mean printing to the actual console at the bottom, NOT the JTAG-UART terminal.
I don't know if a SWI do exist or if I have to call printf somehow...
I would like to print text, integers and/or floats.

This is a "Hello World" in C. How can I replicate that in ARMv7 Assembly?

[image]

CPUlator [Online ARMv7 Simulator](https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=arm-de1soc)

Comment: whats wrong with the assembly you have already?  look up the swi calls for semihosting if you have built that into your application.  (and then what other path than jtag/uart do you have between the host and the target?)  or you can just make life easier and not overcomplicate with C libraries and semihosting, etc.  and use the uart.

Comment: I am not building any app. I have to teach something to a group, and I am looking the simplest way to print text & numbers. Using the uart is overwhelming (not for me, for them). Anyway, could you please elaborate a bit more about the swi?

Answer (score 0):

The following program would work if the semihosting interface were implemented in the simulator you are using - it is working fine with qemu-sytem-arm 4.2.0, the qemu-virt machine and GDB:

[image]

```
.cpu cortex-a9
.syntax unified
.equ    SYS_WRITE0, 0x04
.equ    SYS_EXIT, 0x18
.global _start
_start: mov r0, #SYS_WRITE0
        ldr r1,=hello
        svc #0x123456    
        mov r0, #SYS_EXIT
        ldr r1,=ADP_Stopped_ApplicationExit
        svc #0x123456

hello:  .asciz  "Hello, World!\n"
ADP_Stopped_ApplicationExit:    .word 0x20026
        .end
```

But I am getting the following error message when stepping through the code using the cpulator:

```
Semihosting call r0=0x4 r1=0x18
SVC: This looks like a Semihosting call. Not implemented, so I'll blindly return 0.
Simulator requested a breakpoint
```

This message is rather explicit I would say: cpulator does not seem to be supporting the semihosting interface.

I tried the SYS_WRITEC/0x03 call, but it is not implemented either.

Since even a very basic program using the semihosting interface cannot be executed using cpulator, there is probably no point investigating further why your C program is not working.

I would therefore suggest you to:

1. provide the minimum set of functions required for displaying strings using the JTAG-UART, so that your students would just have to copy/paste and call them in their code - those functions should ideally be compliant with the Arm calling conventions.
2. Use qemu-system-arm in conjunction with GDB in TUI mode, or Eclipse CDT with the support for hardware debugging installed.

Please refer to document [Semihosting for AArch32 and AArch64Release 2.0](https://static.docs.arm.com/100863/0200/semihosting.pdf) for more details.

Comment: @huse: did this help in any way ?